# Selecting multiple criteria in xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to work with an xml feed from a golf tournament in order to display the location of each golfer on a golf course.  I currently want to display every golfer that meets two criteria (being in the top 25, and all golfers who are Canadian).

Here is an example of the xml feed.

```
<GolfDataFeed Type="Leaderboards" Timestamp="3/21/2012 9:18:09 PM">
<Tournament ID="27828" Name="WEGMANS LPGA CHAMPIONSHIP">
<Leaderboard RoundID="4" CutRound="" CutLine="">
<Player ID="82866" WwgrID="975" FirstName="Inbee" LastName="Park" Country="KOR" IsAmateur="False" Rank="1" RankTied="False" StartRank="1" StartRankTied="False" Thru="0" StartTee="1" StartTime="01:25 PM" RoundToPar="0" CumulativeTotal="206" CumulativeToPar="-10" Money="0" TournamentStatus="ACT" RoundStatus="ACT">
<Player ID="82850" WwgrID="434" FirstName="I.K." LastName="Kim" Country="KOR" IsAmateur="False" Rank="2" RankTied="False" StartRank="2" StartRankTied="False" Thru="0" StartTee="1" StartTime="01:25 PM" RoundToPar="0" CumulativeTotal="210" CumulativeToPar="-6" Money="0" TournamentStatus="ACT" RoundStatus="ACT">
<Player ID="88290" WwgrID="3336" FirstName="Jodi" LastName="Ewart Shadoff" Country="ENG" IsAmateur="False" Rank="3" RankTied="False" StartRank="3" StartRankTied="False" Thru="0" StartTee="1" StartTime="01:14 PM" RoundToPar="0" CumulativeTotal="213" CumulativeToPar="-3" Money="0" TournamentStatus="ACT" RoundStatus="ACT">
<Player ID="98006" WwgrID="2982" FirstName="So Yeon" LastName="Ryu" Country="KOR" IsAmateur="False" Rank="4" RankTied="True" StartRank="4" StartRankTied="True" Thru="0" StartTee="1" StartTime="01:14 PM" RoundToPar="0" CumulativeTotal="215" CumulativeToPar="-1" Money="0" TournamentStatus="ACT" RoundStatus="ACT">
</Leaderboard>
</Tournament>
</GolfDataFeed>
```

Here is the code that I've written to select all golfers who are Canadian or in the Top 25

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://services.lpgascoring.com/ws/1.2/leaderboard;
$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml->xpath("///Player[@Rank<'25' or @Country='CAN']") as $Player)
```

I have tried adding in additional lines to select players by their LastName, but this does not seem to work.

```
foreach($xml->xpath("///Player[@Rank<'25' or @Country='CAN' or @LastName='Wie' or @LastName='Peterson']") as $Player)
```

Does anyone have any idea of how you would include more conditional statements in the xpath query?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Your xpaht looks completely OK to me. Only there is not Person with LastName Person or Wie in your example XML.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many forward slashes in your XPath. Try this XPath instead:

```
//Player[@Rank<'25' or @Country='CAN']
```

Comment: I'd like to state that the examples that claimed this had "already had been answered" were in no way similar to this xml code.